# How does the <location path="something" comparison work?

Tags: .net, web-config, location, comparison, authorization

I'm attempting to fix a problem with a legacy site using some old version of Windows Identity Foundation.  One of the problems I've encountered is that since its not an MVC site, I can't do authentication on the controller actions.  Our site has just been forcing authentication on every single page, including all of the ones with set up like this...

```
<location path="Syndication.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

because we have

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

set up due to make WIF work properly.

Therefor, i'm left writing a giant cludge like this in global.asax to try to 'read' the web.config and divine the authorization levels for each `<Location>` item.

```
private void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication htApp = (HttpApplication)sender;

    Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    ConfigurationLocationCollection section = config.Locations;

    foreach (ConfigurationLocation location in section)
    {
        Configuration rootConfiguration = location.OpenConfiguration();
        PropertyInformationCollection props = rootConfiguration.GetSection("system.web/authorization").ElementInformation.Properties;

        foreach (PropertyInformation prop in props)
        {
            AuthorizationRuleCollection arc = prop.Value as AuthorizationRuleCollection;
            if (arc == null) continue;

            foreach (AuthorizationRule rule in arc)
            {
                if (!rule.ElementInformation.IsPresent || rule.Users[0] != "*") continue;

                if (htApp.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension != null)
                {
                    // Clean up the current request name
                    string tmp = htApp.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(htApp.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension))
                    {
                        tmp = tmp.Replace(htApp.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension, string.Empty);
                    }

                    if (tmp.StartsWith("/"))
                    {
                        tmp = tmp.Remove(0, 1);
                    }

                    // something has to make sense at some point
                    // figure out how to compare this to 
                    if (tmp.Contains(location.Path) || location.Path.Contains(tmp))
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.SkipAuthorization = true;
                    }
                }


            }
        }
    }

}
```

This works, but it probably has security holes, and it has HORRIBLE code smell.  And I can't really submit it for a code review because everyone will laugh and think i'm an idiot.

I need to know how to go about getting that boolean value determined in web.config by the `<location path="something">`, and I need to find some way to do it in global.asax, before the authentication action occurs.

How do i determine if my current url's path is 'equivalent' to `<location path` in web.config?

**EDIT:**
I was hoping `this.Context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData` would have what I wanted, but its all empty.

Comment: Did you found your answer?